# Excel VBA: Combining two columns into one column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So currently I am using this code

```
    wsData.Range("b4:b" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("M6")
    wsData.Range("H4:H" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("N6")
```

(lr is the last row)

As well as this cell formula
=CONCATENATE(M6," - ",N6)

To combine two columns into one

I would really like to combine these values in the same way into a single column without using the formula so end users don't have to paste-special out of it, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
wsDest.Range("O6:O" & lr+2).formula = "=CONCATENATE(M6,"" - "",N6)"
```

Eventually you just want to record the formula with the macro recorder while you enter it manually and you get the correct formula with R1C1 notation!

UPDATE:
The recorded script is:

```
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

adapted to your script a possible solution could look like:

```
wsDest.Range("O6:O" & lr + 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(M6,"" - "",N6)"

wsDest.Range("O6:O" & lr + 2).Copy
wsDest.Range("O6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

[image]

Comment: That just enters the formula into those cells, I want to do the formula within vba and put the result into the cell directly so that end users do not need to paste-Special to get the value out of that column when pasting out of it.

Comment: So use the formula and do a copy / pastespecial values

Comment: could you cut and paste the last sentence of my question please